# primeng table - alignFrozen="right" column with scrolldirection="both" and

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to set up a primeng table that scrolls horizontally (`scrolldirection="both"`), has a sticky column to the right (`pFrozenColumn alignFrozen="right"`) and resizable column widths (`[resizableColumns]="true"`).
There is an example for very similar use cases on primeng's demo page from which I cobbled together a sample in this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablevirtualscroll-demo-ktnd9l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

This works fine at a first glance, but once you start removing columns using the dropdown, the whole table seems to shrink horizontally even though I set `columnResizeMode="fit"`. When I then resize the  penultimate column, the frozen column is cut off:

[image: frozen column issue]

Am I doing it wrong or is this unsupported by primeng (Or even a bug)?